# How to run/launch 2+ python scripts at the same in VSC Visual Studio code

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, launch

Until now I could run 2 or more python scripts at the same time in VSC, but today I reinstalled Anaconda and while I run a 5 minute script, when I try to run a 2nd script, it just prints the path to the 2nd script in the middle of the results from the 1st script:

(base) MacBook-Pro-2:~ sebseb$ /Users/sebseb/opt/anaconda3/bin/python /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/my_folder/my_2nd_script.py

I had no launch.json: so I created one using this code in this post:

```
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_compound-launch-configurations
```

I placed it in the same folder as setting.json:

```
Macintosh HD/Users/sebseb/Library/Application Support/Code/User
```

I tried to add this to settings.json:

```
"code-runner.executorMap": {
    "go": "cd $dir && go run .",
},
"code-runner.executorMapByGlob": {
    "$dir/*.go": "go"
},
```

I also installed Code Runner from their website:

```
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com
```

I was getting Code Language not supported, so I fixed that with this video:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T7tXN9PtO9A
```

If feels like VSC can't detect Conda, so I run in terminal:

```
conda update anaconda-navigator
```

But still I cannot run 2 or more scripts at the same time. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think what solved the problem was that I uninstalled the Python Extension, and installed it again, while being in the same Environment. So, 1st select the correct enviroment, then Re-install the Python Extension.

So, click on:

<kbd>SHIFT</kbd> +  <kbd>CMD</kbd> (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> Windows) +  <kbd>P</kbd>

Search for:

```
Python: Select Interpreter
```

Then, restarted VScode.

Then, instead of just click on the "Play" icon to run the code, instead I clicked on the arrow next to it. And instead of doing the "Run Code" I did the "Debug Python File" for the 2nd script.

After doing so the 2nd script opened in another tab which the 1st script was running.

I hope this helps someone.